# server not giving any response for curl code

Tags: php, curl

i am new to curl and making a program which will search using yahoo search engine
here is my code:-

```
<?php
        $handle=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_URL,"http://search.yahooapis.com/ImageSearchServ/V1/imageSearch");
        curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POST,true);
        //curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POSTFEILDS,"appid=$appID&query='water bear&results=5'");
        curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $response=curl_exec($handle);
        curl_close($handle);
        print_r($response);
    ?>
```

when i run this code the browser does not show any error message or any response it just bzy in requesting to the server like an infinite loop.
can you please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should do some more research. I don't think (hope) anyone will give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with your code:

- You're passing a string to post via curl. This is bad. You should prepare carefully the structured data to send.

Example:

```
 $data = array('appid'=>'12345',
               'query'=>'water bear',
               'results'=>5);
 $data = http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;'); // use native helper methods
 curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

- There is a typo in your code: CURLOPT_POST(FEI)LDS should be CURLOPT_POST(FIE)LDS.
- Yahoo's restful search api url's changing in favor of the [BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/) api. Your request uri should look something like this:

> ```
> http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/{service,*}?q={keywords}
> ```

From the documentation:

> BOSS API is an updated service that provides RESTful access to Web,
>   Image, News, Spelling, and Blog search results with a simple pricing
>   scheme based on usage. The service also provides qualifying
>   developer's access to Yahoo! Search Advertising.